# Creating Hydro Hierarchy in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geometric-network

We recently ran at work into this model created by ESRI for the rivers in the US:

https://maps.esri.com/rc/radial/index.html
Code: https://github.com/richiecarmichael/Esri-Hydro-Hierarchy

In order to make QA checks we are trying to embed this sort of model into a geometric network of sewage which has about 5000 line features.

We tried to use the add-in attached to the code (ExportHydroNetwork) in order to apply it on the network, but it didn't even appear on the add-in manager after connecting to the folder (arcmap 10.3)

What are the parameters that this add-in requires for work?

Does it, for example, need a field that classifies level of each line segment?

Or maybe it requires modification in the arcmap environment?

Comment: I reconfigured the addin in Visual Studio 2013 to work with ArcMap 10.4.1 (because that is what I have installed).  It compiles and is visible on the Toolbar list.  After, it assumes the top layer in your TOC is the network layer.

Comment: The addin was built for ArcMap 10.3, so it should work for you if that is what you have installed.